# Associating rows in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to know if it is possible to associate rows in a `GridView`, e.g., I have 2 rows with the same Bundle Id meaning that together they form a Bundle. Given the fact that it is a bundle, I want to have a single expansible row which will expand to show the 2 rows with the same Bundle Id.

All rows have the same properties so, basically, what I want is to put rows with a given property equal to each others under a single row which will expand to show all rows.

I'm new to C# and ASP.NET.

Ex:

"  ID|NAME                 |Price|"

"  15|Strawberry Cheesecake| 15$ |"

"  16|Raspberry  Cheesecake| 17$ |"

Given those 2 rows I want one expansible like,

"+ B1|Raspberry+strawberry | 32$ |"

And then, when I expand it by clicking the + button it shows the other 2.

Comment: Are you after [GridView Grouping](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-GridView-Grouping-Group-similar-GridView-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx)?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many rows you have. You can merge them by whatever the common field you using!

Comment: Check the example now. That's how i want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. I would return the data as a Dataset. I'd loop through the dataset and check if the 'next' row had the same BundleID as 'this' row and, if it has, set a flag to true. When binding the gridview to the Dataset, in the RowDataBound event I'd examine the flag and, if it was true, I'd show a little '+' graphic to click on. This graphic would call a javascript function passing the row number. This function would set the appropriate row's display value. Rows that have the same BundleID as the row before would have their display set to none.

That's the general idea. A bit of javascript then to toggle the display of the rows.

Comment: I was thinking the same. The problem is, during the RowDataBound how will I add the new row in the middle of a gridview? Could it be a private method receiving the rows with the same bundleId and returning the new row with the required changes?

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work by adding a bundle row whenever I found rows with bundleId. During RowDataBound, when I find bundle rows I give them the expand button and make the subrows invisible. Then JQuery took care of the expanding  :)